# trying to make an error popup when username exists

Tags: php, pdo

I have seen many articles on this same question and have been unable to translate their answer to my problem. Basically i made my field 'username' unique in my database and would like to catch an the error of existing username in databse and echo something else out more user friendly. As of now i am able to get the error message but unable to control it.
 I simply want to let the user know when the username already exist in the database.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error i get when adding a member with a already used 'username'.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'theller' for key 'username'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/addMember.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/addMember.php(42): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TESTING/PHP/PHP-TEST/addMember.php on line 42
```

here is my script that is called when my ajax script executes and send over its data.

```
<?php ob_start();
          require_once 'classes/Config.php';
          try {
              $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
              $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              $data = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Testing');
          } catch(PDOException $e) {
                if(($PDO->errorCode() == 23000) || ($PDOStatement->errorCode() == 23000)) {
                  echo 'USER ALREADY EXIST';
                } 
                else {
                 // not a dupe key rethrow error
                 echo 'error';
                }
            }


        $form = $_POST;
        $firstname = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'firstname' ]);
        $lastname = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'lastname' ]);
        $username = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'username' ]);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'password' ]);
        $passMatch = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'pass_match' ]);
        $message = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'message' ]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($form[ 'email' ]);

        if (empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($username) || empty($password)|| empty($passMatch)|| empty($message)|| empty($email)){
            $error = "Complete all fields";
        }
        // Password match
        if ($password != $passMatch){
            $error = "Passwords don't match";
        }
        // Email validation
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error = "Enter a  valid email";
        }
        if(IsInjected($email)) {
            $error = "Bad email value!";
        }
        if(!isset($error)){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Testing ( firstname, lastname, message, email, username, password ) VALUES( :firstname, :lastname, :message, :email, :username, :password )";
            $query = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $query->execute( array( ':firstname'=>$firstname, ':lastname'=>$lastname, ':message'=>$message, ':email'=>$email, ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password ));
            if(!$query->rowCount() > 0){
                echo "exists! cannot insert";
            }else{
            header('Location: thankyou.php'); 
            }

        }
        else{
            echo "error occured: ".$error;
            exit();
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem in my recent project. Please try to replace your `catch` statement with the following:

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
    if(isset($conn))
    {
        if($conn->errorInfo()[0] == 23000) {
            echo 'USER ALREADY EXIST';
        } 
        else {
        // not a dupe key rethrow error
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

Information about `SQLSTATE` error resides in an `errorInfo` array of the PDO object used for the query

Comment: I had to make some adjustments but your script worked for the most part, thank you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :) . Could you tell in which part there was an error ?

Comment: yeah, i was trying to access an error from the wrong array.